# $http.get of json file always returns 404

Tags: angularjs

I want to add to my application a configuration JSON file.
I've added it to my project and tried to get it using $http.get:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/myProject/content.json').success(function (data) {
        // Do stuff...
}).error((data, status, headers, config) => {
        // Failure...
});
```

The problem is that every time I get an error 404.

Comment: That's because the file isn't there, try entering that address `http://localhost/myProject/content.json` directly in your browser.

Comment: The file is there, when I've changed it to txt like Erez said in his answer, it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with your web server mime type configuration - it has none for json, probably.
Try renaming the file extension to .txt or .html and it should work.

You can also add the mime type extension to the server. For IIS express, it's web.config. For example:

```
 <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
```

Comment: Thanks, another option is to go to the IIS manager and configure it to know JSON in the MIME Types.

Answer (score 0):

put content.json file sibling to index.html and use this:

```
$http.get('content.json').success(function (data) {
        // Do stuff...
}).error((data, status, headers, config) => {
        // Failure...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
   **<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>**
</configuration>


This works fine.. as what Erez A. Korn has said.
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 4 store .json file into your root folder of project. all Json file store in same folder.