# AngularJS says json file does not exist

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and am trying to use it to get data from a json file. When I run the program the console reads out there is a 404 error and that the file does not exist.

Here is the angular i am using to try to retrieve the json file.

```
var appLaptops = angular.module('appLaptops', []);

appLaptops.service("laptopsService", function ($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('json/laptops.json')
        .then(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

    this.getLaptops = function () {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})

appLaptops.controller('ctrlLaptops', function ($scope, laptopsService) {
    var promise = laptopsService.getLaptops();
    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.laptop = data;
        //For testing
        console.log($scope.laptop);
    })
});
```

Below I will also attach links to a picture of the folder structure as well as the error readout.

Folder Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8E6W.jpg

Error Readout:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvn2Z.jpg

Comment: is your `json` directory public ? did you try to open `http://localhost:5237/json/laptops.json` in your normal browser first?

Comment: This could also be an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699795/http-get-of-json-file-always-returns-404

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to angular. You have 404 error because IIS doesn't know how to handle `laptops.json` file.

There are two options to solve the issue:

1. Update web.config to let IIS know about the content type of this kind of files (mentioned in comments by QueryLars):

[$http.get of json file always returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699795/http-get-of-json-file-always-returns-404#answer-26699843)

2. Configure HttpRoutes or HttpHandlers

Comment: Thank you, this solved the error for me. I would vote it up but it says i need 15 reputation. But thanks anyways.