# IIS cannot find .json file (404) except its name is "appconfig.json" in angular spa

Tags: json, angular, iis, web-deployment

i have an angular application running which fetches configurations and translations during runtime from static .json files. Once i build the application and deploy it on an IIS 10, requesting any .json file except "appconfig.json" returns a 404 error.

The funny thing is, once i name any .json file to "appconfig.json" the browser returns the result. Here are some examples:

```
GET .../appconfig.json -> works
GET .../config.json -> 404
GET .../config.json.txt -> works
GET .../assets/locale/translations.json -> 404
RENAME config.json to appconfig.json -> works
```

Obviously the IIS can handle .json files (MIME type is also set to application/json). I have absolutely no idea what i could do to solve the problem.

Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

try to add the mime type as shown below:

```
 <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
```

Make sure that you build the application after making changes. check iis log for the sub status code.

link:

[$http.get of json file always returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699795/http-get-of-json-file-always-returns-404)